# Arithmetic on datetime objects

Tags: python

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

I use the today function to get current date, how to perform simple arithmetic on this object so that I can reduce or increase the current date by 1 or 2 (i.e. yesterday or day-before yesterday)

Comment: You may be interested by the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-42a94eedcff96da7fb1f77096b5a3b519c859ba9) python library

Comment: datetime has timedelta module. You can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do the following

```
In [6]: import datetime

# Today
In [7]: datetime.datetime.now()
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 15, 15, 31, 10, 760000)

# Tomorrow's date
In [8]: print datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
2013-01-16 15:31:15.336000

# Day after tomorrow's day
In [9]: print datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
2013-01-17 15:31:52.601000

# Yesterday's date
In [10]: print datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
2013-01-14 15:32:00.081000
```

also works with datetime.datetime.today()

```
In [15]: datetime.datetime.today()
Out[15]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 15, 15, 34, 37, 55000)

In [16]: datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
Out[16]: datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 16, 15, 34, 47, 560000)
```